# Globally Disable Notifications on Lock Screen

Tags: macos, high-sierra, settings, notifications

I'm using macOS High Sierra (version 10.13.3) on a 27"-iMac and on a MacBook Pro.

Almost every time when I'm going to log in, I see various notification on the lock screen, even before I've entered my password. This means, that everybody, who passes by and moves the mouse or presses a key (or opens the lid on the MacBook), will see this notifications too, without being logged in. This is a security issue.

I know, that in the settings, I can deactivate Notifications on Lock Screen for every application. But there are 31 applications that are able to send notifications, and I don't want to click through all of them to deactivate this setting for every application separately.

I might oversee one of them, and when I install a new application, I might forget to deactivate this insecure behavior.

So I want a button where I can deactivate this insecure behavior globally, i.e. for all installed apps, and for all apps that might be installed later.

Is there such a button? If there is one: Where is it?

Comment: even if there were no such button, you can use the information [>here](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/06/disable-notification-center-remove-menu-bar-icon-os-x/) to create two scripts to do it

Comment: @GioValerio: I don't want to disable the entire notification system completely. I like this system, and I often need this notifications. But I only need them when I am logged in. I'm just looking for an easy and reliable way to get rid of the notifications **on the Lock Screen** where everybody can see them, even when nobody is logged in.

Comment: I understood it. The information in the page I referenced explains how to disable and reenable the notifications system, by using the `launchctl` command. That could be combined with an utilitiy like [>Hammerspoon](http://www.hammerspoon.org/) to execute those commands when the lock screen is activated or disactivated

Comment: @GioValerio: But this hack doesn't meet exactly the definition of *"a button"*. I want an easy and reliable solution, not a complicated hack that might fail after the next OS update.

Comment: This seems to be one overlooked security issue, as by default new applications set "Show notification preview" to `always` instead of `when unlocked`. I have been looking as well how to set default to, but did not find solution. There is also StackOverflow question related to this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52661430/setting-unnotificationsettings-lockscreensetting-programmatically?rq=1

Comment: Anyone hoping to add this to MacOS, please drop a feature request.  Hopefully Apple will just add a switch for us: https://www.apple.com/feedback/macos.html

Answer (score 17):

A simple solution (to cancel one by one more complicated):
[image: Simple solution]

A new option "When the screen is locked" has been added under notifications -> do not disturb section in Catalina OS as below:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I expect you are aware of all the interfaces presented, here:

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204079

Specifically:

[image: (UNCHECK) Show notifications on lock screen]

Such as it is, I can appreciate that it can be cumbersome to go through each app one-by-one to uncheck that box (and there may be an unknown on whether every every app will even conform to the spec).

However, at the present time, Apple has not offered a global setting, nor an easy way to multi-select applications to toggle the setting.

So to get any traction toward your request, the best avenue really is to go to the following link and submit your request for enhancement:

https://apple.com/feedback